# Link/unlink existing ParseUser to Facebook account in Android

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

I'm trying to link an existing user to his or her Facebook account using [Parse](https://www.parse.com). After logging into through Parse, the user can go to the `SettingsActivity` and link their Facebook account.

I achieved this by calling `ParseUser.logInInBackground` and then verified it by checking if `ParseUser.getCurrentUser() != null`.

In my `SettingsActivity`, the user can press a 'Connect to Facebook' button, which is supposed to link the account to Facebook, but it's not working. When the user clicks the button, I executed this code below, as per the [Parse Android documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#fbusers-link):

```
mUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

public void onToggleFacebookConnectedClick(View v) {

    if (!ParseFacebookUtils.isLinked(mUser)) {
          ParseFacebookUtils.link(mUser, this, new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException ex) {
              if (ParseFacebookUtils.isLinked(mUser)) {
                  Log.d(Application.APPTAG, "Woohoo, user logged in with Facebook!");
              }
            }
          });
        } else if(ParseFacebookUtils.isLinked(mUser)) {
            ParseFacebookUtils.unlinkInBackground(mUser, new SaveCallback(){
              @Override
              public void done(ParseException ex) {
                if (ex == null) {
                    Log.d(Application.APPTAG, "The user is no longer associated with their Facebook account.");
                }
              }
            });
    }
}
```

I am getting the error: `com.parse.ParseException:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot save a ParseUser until it has been signed up. Call SignUp first.`

The user has already signed up (not using Facebook), so I am confused as to why I'm am getting this message. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I made a silly mistake. I wasn't linking the user correctly because my `Facebook Application ID` was not set correctly in my *Parse App Settings*.